# How to retrieve specific element from open xml Word document mainpart

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I am trying to read some specific text from a word document using open xml SDK.
The structure of the document looks like this.

> #### 1.1.1 Title of the Chapter
>
> *Author's notes: Some text here*
>   *sometimes Author's notes are more than one line.*
>
> #### 1.1.1.1 Title of the sub-chapter
>
> Some text here
>
> #### 1.1.1.2 Title of the next sub-chapter
>
> Some text here.
>
> **End of the Chapter**

**Note: Author's note may not be there in every Chapter**

My requirement is that in a given chapter, whenever there exists **1.1.1.2 Title of the next sub-chapter** I need to get some text under that element, also the **Title of the Chapter** and if the *Author's notes* are present, then the text under that element as well.

This is what I tried:

```
WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordfile, true)          
MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
//Some functions to get the title of the Chapters// 
IEnumerable<Wp.Paragraph> paraList = ParagraphsByStyleName(mainPart, paraStyle1, paraStyle2, paraStyle3);
var purposeParas = paraList.Where(p => Regex.Match(p.InnerText.ToUpper(), "TITLE OF THE NEXT SUB-CHAPTER").Success).ToList();
var myHeaders = purposeParas.Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().ToList();
```

when I tried to iterate through *myHeaders* it gave me the entire Document as the Inner Text. Now I have no way to get to my required text.

So I tried this:

```
var purposeParas = paraList.Where(p => Regex.Match(p.InnerText.ToUpper(), "TITLE OF THE NEXT SUB-CHAPTER").Success).ToList();
var applicability = purposeParas.Select(p => p.NextSibling()).Distinct().ToList();
var myHeader1 = purposeParas.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList();
var myHeader2 = myHeader1.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList();
var myHeader3 = myHeader2.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList();
var myHeaders = myHeader3.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList();
```

This way I was able to read some Chapters. But when Author's notes was more than 1 line, this method fails.
  Any kind suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the question not understandable? Where are the Gods of C#!??

Comment: OpenXML is quite a dead tag, probably because it's hard to debug without having the document of the asker. It's often easier using the [Productivity tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) to inspect your document than waiting for an answer here ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the below solution.
By adding further checks while selecting the previous siblings of the variables  *myHeader3* and *myHeaders* based on the InnerXml content I got to read all the Chapters.

```
for (int h = 0; h < myHeader2.Count; h++ )
            {
                if (myHeader2[h].PreviousSibling().InnerXml.ToLower().Contains("heading4"))
                {
                    myHeaderX = myHeader2[h].Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().ToList();
                    myHeader3.AddRange(myHeaderX.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList());
                }
                if (myHeader2[h].PreviousSibling().InnerXml.ToLower().Contains("heading3"))
                {
                    myHeaderX = myHeader2[h].Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().ToList();
                    myHeader3.AddRange(myHeaderX.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList());
                }
                else if(myHeader2[h].PreviousSibling().InnerXml.ToLower().Contains("author"))
                {   
                    myHeaderX = myHeader2[h].Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().ToList();
                    var x = myHeaderX;
                    for (int ed = 0; ed < 100; ed++)
                    {
                        var y = x.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList();
                        x = y;
                        myHeader3.AddRange(y);
                        IEnumerable<Boolean> z = y.Select(p=>p.PreviousSibling().InnerXml.ToLower().Contains("author"));
                        if(z.First())
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (OpenXmlElement ele in myHeader3 )
            {
                if (ele.PreviousSibling().InnerXml.ToLower().Contains("heading4"))
                {
                    myHeaderX1 = ele.Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().ToList();
                    myHeaders.AddRange(myHeaderX1.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).ToList());
                }
                else if (ele.PreviousSibling().InnerXml.ToLower().Contains("heading3"))
                {
                    if (ele.InnerXml.ToLower().Contains("heading4"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    myHeaderX1 = ele.Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().ToList();
                    myHeaders.AddRange(myHeaderX1.Select(p => p.PreviousSibling()).Distinct().ToList());
                }
            }
```